# Как получить от typescript подсказки о наличии в пропсах элементов store после коннекта?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Т.к. пришел из ангуляра, то реакт осваиваю сразу с подключенным typescript.
Создал вот такой компонент:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class StartComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h3>
            { this.props.num }
          </h3>

          <button onClick={ this.props.increment }>
            Increment
          </button>
         </div>
    );
  }
};

export const Start = connect(
  (storeState: {counter: number}) => ({num: storeState.counter}),
  (dispatch) => ({
    increment: () => {
      dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})
    },
  }),
)(StartComponent);
```

IDE (и браузер при попытке компиляции) ругается:

```
Type error: Property 'num' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.  TS2339
```

Делаем коронный трюк. Пишем:

```
(this.props as any).num
(this.props as any).increment
```

Сохраняем - все работает.

Есть ли способ заставить typescript подхватывать появление новых свойств в пропсах?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь то `Component` универсальный и там можно перегрузить тип пропсов https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L355

Answer (score 0):

Typescript позволяет добавить в код информацию о типах которая будет доступна в момент трансляции или постройки AST [в IDE], поэтому всю информацию о типах нужно прописывать явно:

```
interface Props {
    num: number
    value: String
}

class StartComponent extends Component<Props> {
   // ...
}

const startComponentToProps = (state: {startNum: number, startValue: String}, ownProps: Props): Props => {
    return  {num: state.startNum, value: state.startValue}
}

export default ReactRedux.connect(startComponentToProps)(StartComponent)
```